# How to mirror armature that controls separate parts?

Tags: animation, bones, pose-mode

I want to mirror an armature that controls multiple parts. I did (ctrl p + bone) in pose mode to make the armature control these parts and I want to mirror it like an arm (mirror it with armature and parts so when I move the bones on one side it moves the other side too)[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPua1.png

Comment: if you want to mirror your animation, use the Copy Rotation constraint, but maybe give some details

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want, you can use the *Copy Rotation* constraint. Enable the *Invert* axis, except on X:

[image]

[image]