# Dont work for me: Bird wing animation, syncronized/mirrored armature bones

Tags: rigging, armature, mirror

Tried to search but stuck. I'm trying to make a bird wing animation with syncronized/mirrored armature bones. How do I mirror the movements properly? What is missing in my setup? Have yried Copy Rotation according this thread, but with no success: [How to mirror armature that controls separate parts?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/254457/how-to-mirror-armature-that-controls-separate-parts) but this produced utterly wierd results. What do I do?

### [Blender File download >>](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13o-d1cMyjcdfc7-llK74HwnmCDHBuCwl/view?usp=sharing)[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you want to mirror the pose or the bone position in Edit mode? These are 2 different things. In Pose mode there is a X mirror but you can also copy then Paste Pose Flipped. But maybe share your file?

Comment: Maybe am wrong, but from what I see, I would suggest to rotate your elements 90degress clockwise... It seems your object is along the X axis and should be mirrored on the Y axis

Comment: The pose, I guess ... I'm a bit stranger to the rigging concepts in Blender and gladly poste the file (see edit):)
@B.Pader -- Thanks:) Tried your suggestion but couldn't see any change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Thanks for your kind feedback @moonboots and @B.Pader. After some research I found two movies explaining what I was looking for. Then a lot of experiments before I gained enough skills yet still more to learn. Ie. I have to check out “Paste Pose Flipped”.

https://recordit.co/kTjMuS2g5B

Useful guides:

A. https://video.blender.org/w/tYAZxyNHYtguGXMPF4BS4Q?start=2m5s

B. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bhRrVn5gXZk

Tips (what I learned from this thread:)

1. Selecting the bones and click ctrl-A, apply Pose as Rest Pose, is VERY helpful as a start
2. Copy Rotation Modifier: A crucial thing is to comprehend the relationship between Target and Owner where the former moves the latter!
3. Copy Rotation Modifier: The concept with XYZ with or with out Invert and the “Space” plus Offset is hard to grasp as a newcomer but a vigorous click-and-check approach will pay off in the end:)
4. Some knowledge using vertex groups and weight paint is VERY helpful.
5. The ability to understand what was going on in the Outliner is indeed important. Use it for selections. That way it is much easier to click between the different modes.

[image: Useful tips]